# Shallow render returns empty object, wrapper.debug() shows fully rendered component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-bootstrap

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I have not found the answer yet. I am trying to test a functional component  that renders react-bootstrap components.  The smoke test works fine, but trying to test if it renders the correct children has been tricky. I have been following the docs for shallow rendering, but my wrapper returns: `ShallowWrapper {}` even though wrapper.debug() returns:

```html
<div id="header">
  <Navbar color="faded" tag="nav" expand={false}>
    <NavbarBrand id="logo" href="/" tag="a">
      <img src="logo.png" id="logo-img"  alt="stool-logo" />
      Scores
    </NavbarBrand>
    <div id="header-flex-container">
      <Nav tag="ul" vertical={false} />
    </div>
  </Navbar>
</div>
```

This is my component (still a WIP, please ignore unused imports):

```js
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar, NavLink, NavItem, NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";
import Logo from "../assets/logo.png";

import "../styles/Header.css";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div id="header">
      <Navbar color="faded">
        <NavbarBrand id="logo" href="/">
          <img src={Logo} id="logo-img" alt="stool-logo" />
          Scores
        </NavbarBrand>
        <div id="header-flex-container">
          <Nav></Nav>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavLink, NavItem, NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";

import Header from '../Header';

describe('Header', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(<Header/>)
  });

  it('renders the navbar', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    console.log(wrapper);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find(Navbar)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
  })
});
```

I am not totally sure where I am going wrong, since the component is being rendered properly.  I have also tried using `mount`, but get the same error each time: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`.

I have also tried `expect(wrapper.hasClass('navbar')).toEqual(true)` but get an actual of `false`. I tried using `.dive()` on the wrapper but get: `TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components`

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using `expect` from Jest with [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) style.

You have 2 options, you can either add `chai` to your project and add this import to your tests:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
```

Or, you can rewrite your test like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Navbar).length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but tried this, and got this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`.

Comment: Did you install `chai` (`yarn add chai` / `npm i --save-dev chai`)? also have you tried the second solution? I tried both before answering

Comment: I only tried the second solution.  That is strange that you got it to work.  Which version of jest are you running?

Comment: You can't get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined` with the second solution, since you aren't accessing `have` anymore

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined


      14 |     console.log(wrapper);
      15 |     console.log(wrapper.debug());
    > 16 |     expect(wrapper.find(Navbar).length).toEqual(1);
         |     ^
      17 |   })
      18 | });

Comment: sorry for the messy look in the comment, but that is the output in the console

Comment: Ah WAIT!!! restarted the test suite and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use .toHaveLength

```
it('renders the navbar', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    console.log(wrapper);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find(Navbar)).toHaveLength(1);
  })
```